# Issue word counting code in java submethod

Tags: java

I am having trouble with this code.  The end goal is to take a string and count the number of words over a length given by the user. The user can give any input for the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is over here:

```
char ch2 = original.charAt(i-1);
```

Your loop starts with `i = 0`, so you are trying to access character at -1 which is invalid. Start your loop from 1 instead as below:

```
 for(int i = 1; i<original.length(); i++){
```

Comment: @Yassin Hajaj: That would not fix anything.

Comment: No. See that OP is trying to access ith character as well using `char ch = original.charAt(i);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line:

```
char ch2 = original.charAt(i-1);
```

When `i` is `0`, this line attempts to find the character at index `-1`. I would recommend initializing `i` as `1` instead of `0` to avoid this problem.